# open modal after form submit, i dont know ajax :(

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I am trying to send data from a form to a modal to verify the data and after proced to send, but this part of the data needs the post from thr form, and this one is not working when it call the modal, I do not know how to use ajax can someone give me a way to go with this thank you

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<?php
if ($_POST) {

  $amount = $_POST['precio']*100; 
     echo $amount;
     $miObj->setParameter("DS_MERCHANT_AMOUNT",$amount);

 }
?>
<form data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" method="POST" action="" >

   <input name="precio" id="precio" />
   <input  class="btn btn-info" type="submit" >
</form>



<div class="container">

   

  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">

 

    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Confirma tu compra</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div id="imagen">IMAGEN COMPRA</div>
          <img src="" alt="mando">
          <div class="details-area" id="detailsArea">
   <h1 style="color:#007acc">Opciones Seleccionadas</h1>  
  </div>
                 <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="nombre">Nombre:</label>
                  <input type="name" class="form-control" id="nombre">
                </div>
                 <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="apellido">Apellido</label>
                  <input type="name" class="form-control" id="Apellido">
                </div>
                 <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="direccion">Dirección</label>
                  <input type="address" class="form-control" id="direccion">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="telefono">Telefono</label>
                  <input type="phone" class="form-control" id="telefono">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="email">Email address:</label>
                  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email">
                </div>
             
            <div align="right"> <h3>Total Compra <span id="AddToCartPriceID2">&nbsp $00.00</span></h3></div>
              
        </div>

         

        <div class="modal-footer"> 
    
    <form name="frm" action="https://sis-t.redsys.es:25443/sis/realizarPago" method="POST" target="_blank" style="margin-top:10px">
           <input  name="DS_MERCHANT_AMOUNT" value="<?php echo $amount; ?>"/></br>
     <input type="hidden" name="Ds_SignatureVersion" value="<?php echo $version; ?>"/></br>
     <input type="hidden" name="Ds_MerchantParameters" value="<?php echo $params; ?>"/></br>
     <input type="hidden" name="Ds_Signature" value="<?php echo $signature; ?>"/></br>
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" >Confirmar</button>
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </form>

        </div>

     

      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Sounds like the perfect time to learn Ajax! Instead of waiting for someone to do it all for you, you can use this time to learn how to do it. I personally like jquery Ajax because it's easy to implement. Read the docs, try it, come back when/if you get stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <form id="frm"  method="POST">
            <input name="precio" id="precio" />
            <input  class="btn btn-info" type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
  </form>
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Confirma tu compra</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div id="imagen">IMAGEN COMPRA</div>
          <img src="" alt="mando">
          <div class="details-area" id="detailsArea">
            <h1 style="color:#007acc">Opciones Seleccionadas</h1>   
              </div>
                 <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="nombre">Nombre:</label>
                  <input type="name" class="form-control" id="nombre">
                </div>
                 <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="apellido">Apellido</label>
                  <input type="name" class="form-control" id="Apellido">
                </div>
                 <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="direccion">Dirección</label>
                  <input type="address" class="form-control" id="direccion">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="telefono">Telefono</label>
                  <input type="phone" class="form-control" id="telefono">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="email">Email address:</label>
                  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email">
                </div>

                <div align="right"> <h3>Total Compra <span id="AddToCartPriceID2">&nbsp $00.00</span></h3></div>

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer"> 
                <form name="frm" action="https://sis-t.redsys.es:25443/sis/realizarPago" method="POST" target="_blank" style="margin-top:10px">
                    <input  name="DS_MERCHANT_AMOUNT" value="<?php echo $amount; ?>"/></br>
                    <input type="hidden" name="Ds_SignatureVersion" value="<?php echo $version; ?>"/></br>
                    <input type="hidden" name="Ds_MerchantParameters" value="<?php echo $params; ?>"/></br>
                    <input type="hidden" name="Ds_Signature" value="<?php echo $signature; ?>"/></br>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" >Confirmar</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $("#frm").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            data: $("#frm").serialize(),
            url : 'url',
            success : function(data){
               $("#myModal").modal("show");

            }
        });
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

Comment: hi dipali thanks for answer, i am using the script you give me, but now it show the modal but doesn't  load the php, what i am doing wrong?, thankyou

Comment: Did you set the value of given url. Please share your php code

Comment: hi dipali, thanks for answer i have the php in the sme page did i have to put it in another file? thanks


<php if ($_POST) {

  $amount = $_POST['precio']*100; 
     echo $amount;
     
     // Se Rellenan los campos
     $miObj->setParameter("DS_MERCHANT_AMOUNT",$amount);

 }
?>

Comment: You need to put php code in another file and sent the request of ajax on php file, need to set path of another file in ajax url: perameter.

Comment: hi dipali, if i use a new file there is no sense to use the ajax, the idea is load the variable in the modal , thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
   validated_form.html

 <html>
    <head>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function validate()
    {
     var error="";
     var name = document.getElementById( "name_of_user" );
     if( name.value != "" )
     {
      name = name.value;
      document.getElementById( "name" ).innerHTML = name;
      return false;
     }
    }

    </script>

    </head>
    <body>

    <form method="POST" action="getdata.php" onsubmit="return validate();">
     <input type="text" name="username" id="name_of_user">
     <input type="submit" name="submit_form" value="Submit">
    </form>

// use id=name in your model form field
    <input type="text" id="name" >

    </body>
    </html>


=====================================

    getdata.php



    <?php
    if( isset( $_POST['submit_form'] ) )
    {
     validate_data($data)
     {
      $data = trim($data);
      $data = stripslashes($data);
      $data = strip_tags($data);
      $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
      $data = mysqli_real_escape_string($data);
      return $data;    
     }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: hi sunil thanks for answer, i will try to use ajax, because  i have not much clear yur answer thanks